# CSS Menu - text spacing with hover highlighting

Tags: html, css

Page layout: 960px wide, centered. The navbar however, is 100% wide, the links within the navbar are centered with the 960px. The navbar has a background of #333333. I want the words to be spaced out 20px apart. When I mouse over the link, I want the background color to highlight the text 10px to the left and 10px to the right so it looks nice. Whenever I seem to hover over, it adds additional spacing. When I removed it from the a:hover the background gets rid of any padding before/after the word. Any help would be appreciated!

HTML

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar_menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar_menu {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 960px;
}

.navbar_menu ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar_menu ul li {
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is suprising. but you will get extra spacing from the End-of-Line characters between each List Item. Put them all in one line without white spaces as below:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="">link</a></li><li><a href="">link</a></li><li><a href="">link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think the margin: 0 auto; is what's messing with the height and width.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me.  When you refer to 'spaced out' you typically are referring to either padding or margins.  These are important concepts to learn - there are lots of great tutorials out there.  I added padding to the left and right of the link inside the list item.  Because you haven't specified a width for each list item, the link determines the size and adds 10px to each side, giving a 20px space between each item.

```
.navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar_menu {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 960px;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar_menu ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar_menu ul li {
  display: inline;
}
.navbar_menu ul li a {
  padding:0 10px 0 10px;
}
.navbar_menu ul li a:hover{
  background-color:#c9c;
}
```